# Auto Updates google play

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my application on google play a few hours ago. I'm not expecting it to show on google play in an instant of course. Maybe I have to wait for 24 hrs.

The thing is I remember I saw this but not sure where, cause it's not in here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html and not sure if it's true. Does google play notifies all the user who downloaded my app through notification of course everytime I update my application on google play by changing the version code higher than the previous?

For example from versioncode = 1 to versioncode = 2? Do google do this or do I have to programmatically notify the user if theres and update? Thanks!

Comment: The market shows an update and will notify (with a notification) that there are updates available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Google Play app on the device automatically checks for updates to all apps installed by the user (yours or otherwise) and notifies them of updates. I'm not sure as to how often it checks, but I think it's 5 or 6 times a day.

Comment: It just checks available updates, does it? Are they installed as well?

Comment: If the user has automatic updating enables, they will be installed as well. If automatic updates are disabled or an app's permissions have changed then the user has to manually open the Google Play app and click the update button(s).

Comment: Not without user consent, and even then only if your permissions reamin the same.

Comment: Permission changes aren't the problem anymore but I'ver seen devices that show "update available" and still have not installed it 3 days later. Really annoying if you have customers who can hardly wait for an update but are not able to manually start installation. :/